# Go binary encoding variant vs fixed slice length

Tags: go

I need to encode integer keys as byte slices for a KV database.
I want to make the encoding smaller and cut the zero padding.
I thought the variant encoding from the binary package would be the way to go.

But in both cases, variant and fixed, the byte slice length is the same.
Just different bits arrangement since first bit is used as a flag.
I assumed the variant encoding would cut the "extra fat". No.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    x := 16
    y := 106547

    fmt.Println(x)
    fmt.Println(y)

    // Variant
    bvx := make([]byte, 8)
    bvy := make([]byte, 8)

    xbts := binary.PutUvarint(bvx, uint64(x))
    ybts := binary.PutUvarint(bvy, uint64(y))

    fmt.Println("Variant bytes written x: ", xbts)
    fmt.Println("Variant bytes written y: ", ybts)

    fmt.Println(bvx)
    fmt.Println(bvy)

    fmt.Println("bvx length: ", len(bvx))
    fmt.Println("bvy length: ", len(bvy))

    // Fixed
    bfx := make([]byte, 8)
    bfy := make([]byte, 8)

    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(bfx, uint64(x))
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(bfy, uint64(y))

    fmt.Println(bfx)
    fmt.Println(bfy)

    fmt.Println("bfx length: ", len(bfx))
    fmt.Println("bfy length: ", len(bfy))

}
```

My question is. Do I have to splice the byte slice manually with variant encoding to get rid of the extra bytes?
Since put `PutUvariant` returns the number of bytes written, I can just splice the byte slice.

Is this the right way to do it?
If not, what is the correct way to make the slices smaller?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Package binary](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/)
>
> ```
> import "encoding/binary"
> ```
>
> [func PutUvarint](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#PutUvarint)
>
> ```
> func PutUvarint(buf []byte, x uint64) int
> ```
>
> PutUvarint encodes a uint64 into buf and returns the number of bytes
>   written. If the buffer is too small, PutUvarint will panic.

---

Fix your code:

```
bvx := make([]byte, binary.MaxVarintLen64)
bvy := make([]byte, binary.MaxVarintLen64)
bvx = bvx[:binary.PutUvarint(bvx[:cap(bvx)], uint64(x))]
bvy = bvy[:binary.PutUvarint(bvy[:cap(bvy)], uint64(y))]
```

---

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    x := 16
    y := 106547

    fmt.Println(x)
    fmt.Println(y)

    // Variant
    bvx := make([]byte, binary.MaxVarintLen64)
    bvy := make([]byte, binary.MaxVarintLen64)

    bvx = bvx[:binary.PutUvarint(bvx[:cap(bvx)], uint64(x))]
    bvy = bvy[:binary.PutUvarint(bvy[:cap(bvy)], uint64(y))]

    fmt.Println("Variant bytes written x: ", len(bvx))
    fmt.Println("Variant bytes written y: ", len(bvy))

    fmt.Println(bvx)
    fmt.Println(bvy)

    fmt.Println("bvx length: ", len(bvx))
    fmt.Println("bvy length: ", len(bvy))

    // Fixed
    bfx := make([]byte, 8)
    bfy := make([]byte, 8)

    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(bfx, uint64(x))
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(bfy, uint64(y))

    fmt.Println(bfx)
    fmt.Println(bfy)

    fmt.Println("bfx length: ", len(bfx))
    fmt.Println("bfy length: ", len(bfy))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/XN46KafMY23

Output:

```
16
106547
Variant bytes written x:  1
Variant bytes written y:  3
[16]
[179 192 6]
bvx length:  1
bvy length:  3
[16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[51 160 1 0 0 0 0 0]
bfx length:  8
bfy length:  8
```

Comment: Why do we need to do this `bvx[:cap(bvx)]` on the original slice? `bvx = bvx[:binary.PutUvarint(bvx, uint64(x))]` works just as well...

Comment: @r.sendecky: Because my code works all of the time and your code only works some of the time. For example, your code panics, mine doesn't: https://play.golang.org/p/sx1k7hA6OqN

Comment: I understand that your code works I am just trying to understand why we need the `cap()` there. "Because my code works and yours does not" is not really an answer. I mark it as resolved anyway. But I still would like to know why if it is not difficult to explain...